# How to prevent untrusted string parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, security, parameters

For security reasons, I don't want specific method to receive non-programmer or non-compiler time strings, how could I do this?

```
readonly String OK_STR = "some text";
String BAD_STR = "another text";

public void SetSecureStr(String str)
{
    //Use the string for security purpose
}

//Somewhere in the code
SetSecureStr(OK_STR); //Accepted
SetSecureStr(OK_STR + "Programmer passed this staticlly!"); //Accepted (If not possible to implement, forget about it)
SetSecureStr(BAD_STR); //Throw exception, BAD_STR is modifiable
SetSecureStr(OK_STR + untrustedVar); //Throw exception, concatenation with modifiable
SetSecureStr(String.Format("{0}", OK_STR)); //Throw exception, not const
```

Comment: OK_STR is modifiable as well. `static` in C# does *not* mean "const".

Comment: static String can still be modified. Did you mean readonly or const?

Comment: Err, OK_STR is also modifiable - `static` does not mean `const`!

Comment: You want to implement SetSecureStr() ?

Comment: Why would `BAD_STR` be diallowed? It is (to use the words from your post) a "compiler time string" (aka literal).

Comment: I don't mean const, I mean readonly, and that's why BAD_STR is not allowed - Corrected

Comment: Yes Gunner, I want to find a way inside SetSecureStr() to know if the String is readonly or not so that I could throw exception if not.

Comment: The readonly keyword differs from the const keyword. A const field can only be initialized at the declaration of the field. A readonly field can be initialized either at the declaration or in a constructor. Therefore, readonly fields can have different values depending on the constructor used. Also, although a const field is a compile-time constant, the readonly field can be used for run-time constants, as in this line: public static readonly uint l1 = (uint)DateTime.Now.Ticks; - const (C# Reference) - MSDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came finally with a solution which is hybrid between the two previously proposed answers:

```
public class SqlQuery
{
    private SqlQuery() { }

    private static UInt32 sqlQueriesCount = 0;

    public static UInt32 INBOUND_UPDATE_CALLBACK_NUM = sqlQueriesCount++;
    public static UInt32 INBOUND_UPDATE_DEST_ADDR_SUBUNIT = sqlQueriesCount++;
    public static UInt32 INBOUND_UPDATE_DEST_BEARER_TYPE = sqlQueriesCount++;
    //...etc

    private static readonly Dictionary<UInt32, String> queries = new Dictionary<UInt32, String>
    {
        {SqlQuery.INBOUND_UPDATE_CALLBACK_NUM, "UPDATE inbound SET callbackNum = ? WHERE id = ?"},
        {SqlQuery.INBOUND_UPDATE_DEST_ADDR_SUBUNIT, "UPDATE inbound SET destAddrSubunit = ? WHERE id = ?"},
        {SqlQuery.INBOUND_UPDATE_DEST_BEARER_TYPE, "UPDATE inbound SET destBearerType = ? WHERE id = ?"},
        //...etc
    };

    public static String GetQueryText(UInt32 queryKey)
    {
        String query = null;
        if (SqlQuery.queries.TryGetValue(queryKey, out query) == false)
        {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(String.Format("Query must be paramerized query stored within SqlQuery class, provided queryKey: {0}", queryKey));
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(SqlQuery.GetQueryText(SqlQuery.INBOUND_UPDATE_CALLBACK_NUM), con);
```

Comment: This way I don't need to type the query string again when calling, nor need to use meaningless index numbers to point to the preferred string. I could now point to the string using static int meaningful variable.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to whitelist against things *inside* your ability to control, such as enums or *local* constants (or a local whitelist from configuration data if the list isn't fixed ahead of time).

As a *rough* check, you could check whether it is *interned*, since all literals will be interned automatically via `ldstr`; but note you can **explicitly** intern too, so this isn't 100% safe.

And of course, in any event with the question *as asked*, if that string happens *somewhere else* as a literal (unconnected to this code) it would still be trusted. I suggest a whitelist is safer...

A whitelist could be as simple as:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> whiteList = new HashSet<string> {
    "good", "more good"
};
... check via whiteList.Contains(s)
```

but note that this is still mutable at runtime (via reflection if necessary).

Comment: I want to implement something just like CA2100 warning of VS2010, or at least something that wraps say SQL queries and pass it to the command executor safely with suppressing the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accepting string values, number all your strings, and pass the number:

```
string[] good_strings = {"some text"};
public void SetSecureStr(int stringno)
{
    string s = good_strings[stringno];
}
```

Computed strings won't be supported with that approach.

Comment: If you are hard-coding against a number, an enum would usually be preferable

Comment: Is not there a way to check for the String origin or declaration propertieses?

Comment: No, it's not possible - not without writing the .NET virtual machine.